# Google Language in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, language, google-drive

When ever I use Google products in Firefox the page is in Thai. I am in Thailand, but I don't get this problem when using Chrome.

If I manage to find the language selector to change to English, its soon goes back into  Thai.

I have checked the settings in my Google account and they are English, I have tried clearing my cookies and cache but the problem still persists.

Any suggestions to correct this?

Comment: [Here](/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english "How can I force my browser to search Google in English?") and [here](/questions/59118/how-do-you-make-googles-interface-always-be-in-your-chosen-language "How do you make Google's interface always be in your chosen language?") are questions regarding the search interface language that may help here, too. And [here](/questions/408446/set-preferred-language-in-chrome-and-other-google-services "Set preferred language in Chrome and other Google services") is a question for Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Two settings you could check are:

1. In Firefox; **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Options** > **Content** > **Choose**, English (en) or a preferred variant should be on top (the corresponding setting in Firefox [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) is `intl.accept_languages`).
2. [General.useragent.locale](http://kb.mozillazine.org/General.useragent.locale) in about:config should have the preferred language code (the one chosen in the previous step would suffice e.g. en-US).